# Transferring textbox value from one page to popup page in a variable in vb

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

i have a textbox on page1.

Same page1 have a button1 > which popup popup1.

```
Me.btnCopy.Attributes.Add("onClick", "popup1();")
```

.

```
function popup1() {
  try {
var sReturn = window.showModalDialog('iframe.asp?scr=popup1.aspx&title=" & Server.UrlEncode("Enter") & "&',null, 'dialogHeight:150px;dialogWidth:450px;status:no;help:no;scroll:yes;resizable:yes;');
```

......

i have to use value of textbox page1 on popup1 to do further task.
How can i retrieve it.

Comment: Can you show me all of your ASP.NET Code-Behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the value in the URL call to the popup (as a GET parameter)

```
function popup1() {
    var textBoxValue = <%= TextBox.ClientID %>.value ;
    var sReturn = window.showModalDialog('iframe.asp?val='+textBoxValue+'&scr=popup1.aspx&title=" & Server.UrlEncode("Enter") & "&',null, 'dialogHeight:150px;dialogWidth:450px;status:no;help:no;scroll:yes;resizable:yes;');
```

then

in the page iframe.asp or popup1.aspx, you should be able to get the value on the page load.

eg. in dotnet :

```
dim textBoxValue as string = Request("val").toString
```

Comment: its fine . but why its giving error object reference not set to an instance of object when i am putting 
"dim textBoxValue as string = Request("val").toString" 
this line in pageload

Comment: I guess in the "iframe.asp", you put the popup1.aspx as a source on the iframe in this page.
The src "popup1.aspx" should be also called with the "?var=value" parameter in its url then, as you are working in the pageLoad of popup1, right ?

Also to avoid null reference exception, you can remove the .toString code, but you should check if this variable is nothing somewhere later.